# Should I use the Transients API to temporarily hold edited attachements?

Tags: transient

I'm building a store that allows users to order prints of photos. If the user orders a photo that has a different dimension than the one the photo is originally, they are prompted to crop the photo. The photo would only be held for a short time period, say twenty five minutes.

Is it appropriate to use the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to hold the cropped photo data?

Answer (score 2):

Transients would be a good option for sure assuming the data is crop instructions only. Transients work best performance-wise if you have memcached installed as well as an object cache plugin. As a caveat, don't rely on object cache to be 100% solid. It is volatile and can be corrupted rather easily. I've found this to be quite true at times.

If you want a more fail-safe storage, you could just use transients without object cache as the key/value pairs will be stored as an expiring option in the options table.

Either way, transients are a convenient way to store temporary data. I would check out [Mark Jaquith's TLC Transient](https://github.com/markjaquith/WP-TLC-Transients) class. It's a huge help getting transients setup in your theme.